# How to add source files to a gradle project using an external gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The java classes in my project have dependencies on some files. These files should automatically be imported when I try to sync all gradle files in Android Studio. Right now I have a task in my build.gradle file which runs an external tasks from another build file (compile.gradle). The compile.gradle file will then copy the necessary folders into my main project.

Everything works fine if I call the task manually at first and then syncing the whole project. But as soon as I try to sync the project, without manually calling the task, the external compile.gradle file doesn't get executed and the stack trace shows a "class not found" error.

```
task thrift(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = '../other_project/compile.gradle'
    startParameter.projectProperties = ['example.bin.java': example_bin_java,
        'example.src': example_src] //Should not be important
    tasks = ['clean', 'compile', ...]
}
```

I already read somewhere that I should not import these files via external tasks because they only get executed in the "execution phase" (Lifecycle: Initialization, Configuration, Execution) and apparently this phase does not get called if I sync or execute the project. However I cannot come up with a solution for this problem. I probably have to use another way to execute the tasks from an external gradle file (without a GradleBuild task).

How do I force/declare the execution of external tasks while syncing all gradle files in Android Studio?

It will probably solve the problem if I copy the external tasks to the build.gradle file. But this is not a soution I am looking for (redundant code...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added thrift.execute() to the grade file. 
Maybe not the best way to force the task execution but this results 
into the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a couple of different ways.  You could create a separate "module" for your external code to be built as a library and make your app have a compile dependency on that module (project in gradle - a lovely discrepancy between gradle and IntelliJ terms.)  Or, if you wish to keep the task based structure you have now, you can modify the existing Android specific tasks to be dependent on your new task:

```
androidDependencies.dependsOn thrift
```

Now when you perform a sync (or `gradlew assemble`) the build should pick up the dependencies properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to say that this specific sub-project only uses the java plugin and not the android one. So where do I add the "androidDependencies" keyword exactly? My gradle build doesn't know this one.

Comment: This should be in your Android project's gradle file. You might be able to get away with 'assemble' instead as that is a task defined by the Java plugin.

Comment: Hey, I tried the assemble now too. It sets the dependencies properly but the execution order is still wrong. I really think the external gradle file doesn't get executed if I just automatically sync the whole project instead of executing the specific (type:GradleBuild) task. 

It works if I add the tasks to the "Before launch" dependencies in the run/debug configurations.... still this is not the solution I want.